# Skrollr once more, adding white space

Tags: css, skrollr

skrollr is adding white space [to this page](http://www.luxvitae.ch)

test it with the chrome device mode (F12, then the phone icon)

then use an ipad and hit refresh

I tried:

```
        lux.view.skrollr = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false
});

        lux.view.skrollr = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: true
});
```

and I tried removing all skrollr attributes from the last element.

when I don't init skrollr, this problem does not occur.

any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused only for mobile devices.

The reason behind it was that i used jqueries animate to scroll to some parts of the page. So e.g. it would snap to a full page when scrolling really close to it.

as well I was using a scroll animation when clicking on the menu

this has to be replaced with skrollrs scrolling functions

e.g.

```
var someOffset = skrollr.get().relativeToAbsolute(document.getElementById('foo'), 'top', 'top');
skrollr.get().setScrollTop(someOffset );
```

or

```
skrollr.get().animateTo(someOffset);
```